# How to finding the Jordan form of this $6 \times 6$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I have the following matrix and I need to find its Jordan form.

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
-3 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

So I first need to find the characteristic polynomial of each block

For $B_1: P_{B_1}(\lambda)=(\lambda +1)^2$

For $B_2: P_{B_2}(\lambda)=(\lambda +1)^2(\lambda-3)$

For $B_3:  P_{B_3}(\lambda)=(\lambda-3)$

a. for $B_1,B_2$ it is said that there are "product of linear elements"? although $(\lambda +1)^2=\lambda^2+2\lambda+1$?

Next we have to find the minimal polynomial, we know that each root of  characteristic polynomial need to be in the minimal polynomial so

For $B_1: M_{B_1}(\lambda)=(\lambda +1)^2$ has $(A+I)^2\neq 0$

For $B_2: P_{B_2}(\lambda)=(\lambda +1)^2(\lambda-3 )$ has $(A+I)^2(A-3*I)\neq 0$

For $B_3:  P_{B_3}(\lambda)=(\lambda-3)$

So the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is: $P_{A}(\lambda)=(\lambda +1)^4(\lambda-3)^2$

How do I find the minimal polynomial when I know that it is equal to the LCM?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is the product of those of the blocks, which is (*λ* + 1)⁴(*λ* – 3)².

For the minimal polynomial, the LCM of the exponents of (*λ* + 1) for the blocks is 2, and that of the exponents of (*λ* – 3) is 1, so altogether, the minimal polynomial for the matrix is (*λ* + 1)²(*λ* – 3).